# bitcoin-qt no debug.log file

Tags: c++, bitcoin

First of all, i was working on making the new genesis block for educational purpose.

I changed the ntime to current epoch time, and changed nnonce to 0 in src\main.cpp

Now i compiled and run the qt. it says assertion failed src\main.cpp line 2870

expression: hash == hashgenesisblock.

Okay, so i went to %appdata% folder, and then there is COIN folder. but there is an empty db.log file, and there is no debug.log file. I run the wallet even through testnet and noirc, still no debug.log file appears. can anyone help? I need the debug.log file to get the gen block hash and merkel root hash.

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: main.cpp is this file
https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master-1.5/src/main.cpp

and i am using same git to makefile

Comment: Seems like you'd want to look in the code and see where that file is written to and then figure out why nothing is being written to it.  You know, debugging.

Comment: @user2185284: how is this qt related? Please remove that tag.

Comment: file is supposed to be written to %appdata%\DogeCoin folder. I posted bitcoin here because more people are familiar to bitcoin than dogecoin. But they're kind of same thing.

Comment: @LaszloPapp removed the qt tag

Comment: It would appear you need to pass `-debug` or `-debuglog` on the command line, are you doing so?

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you so much! that was it. lol I did -debug from cmd and it generated the debuglog. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add "-debuglog" to the QT project setting

Answer (score -1):

after 0.8.6 all the debug code for playing out genblock hash failures is gone. its all rebased and not in main.cpp like 99% of the guides tell you. Give up or figure out another way.